# Obter total de itens relacionamento 1:N

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo duas tabelas Produto e Itens - estas tabelas possue relacionamento Pai / Filho respectivamente. Gostaria de saber como faço para obter o total de itens da tabela Itens sabendo que cada cliente pode possuir mais de um Pedido e que cada pedido é composto por diversos itens? Se possível, gostaria de saber também como faço para obter o valor total dos itens.

Estou utilizando EntityFramework com Code First. A query já possui o Include mas até o momento ao acrescentar o GroupBy + Count o resultado retornado é o total de Pedios (tabela pai).

Desde já agradeço pela força.

Comment: Olá @urlflavio. Bem vindo ao StackOverFlow em Português. Faça um [tour] para entender como o site funciona. Aproveitando, poderia postar o que você tem código? Somente com essas informações fica complicado te ajudar. Poste o modelo de suas classes e tente explicar um pouco mais o que quer.

Comment: @urlflavio, você poderia postar algum código? O que você quer? Não ficou claro, você quer a query, ou código em c# que executará a query para você?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou supondo a seguinte construção dos seus *Models*:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PedidoProduto> PedidoProdutos { get; set; } // Aqui seria sua relação de itens
}

public class Pedido
{
    [Key]
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PedidoProduto> PedidoProdutos { get; set; }
}

public class PedidoProduto
{
    [Key]
    public int PedidoProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

> Gostaria de saber como faço para obter o total de itens da tabela Itens sabendo que cada cliente pode possuir mais de um Pedido e que cada pedido é composto por diversos itens?

Pode ser feito assim:

```
var pedido = db.Pedidos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PedidoId == 1);
var itens = pedido.PedidoProdutos.Select(pp => pp.Produto).ToList();
```

> Se possível, gostaria de saber também como faço para obter o valor total dos itens.

Assim:

```
var total = pedido.PedidoProdutos.Sum(pp => pp.Produto.Preco * pp.Quantidade);
```

Comment: Pessoal, antes de mais nada gostaria de agradecer pela ajuda de todos! Ao ler a minha pergunta vi que realmente não deixei muito claro a minha duvida.

Comment: Pessoal, antes de mais nada gostaria de agradecer pela ajuda de todos! Cigano Morrison, ao ver o seu exemplo o mesmo possui uma lógica mais adequada a minha necessidade. A minha única duvida é, devo salvar nas tres tabelas a cada novo pedido? se sim, como faria para salvar nas tres via Entity Framework? Desde já agradeço pela força!

Comment: O correto é você salvar em `Pedido` e `PedidoProduto`. Para esta nova dúvida, o melhor é uma nova pergunta.